# Is there any way to check if migrations are ended

Tags: php, laravel, migration

My question is if there is any way to check if migrations are ended. Maybe some events or hooks or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to listen for the [`Illuminate\Console\Events\CommandFinished`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Console/Events/CommandFinished.php) event to determine when the `php artisan migrate` command has finished running (by comparing the `$command` property of the event).

If you want a hook for each migration *file*, one option is to extend `Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator` with your own class and override the `runUp()` method to fire an event afterward. I don't see any obvious built-in hooks for individual migrations, however. A much more simple solution would be to dispatch an event yourself from within each migration's `up()` method.