# How can i trigger event after "php artisan migrate"?

Tags: laravel

I want to trigger an event as soon as i complete migrating my files because i want to add one extra column in my table. And in that column i want to copy all the data of another column.

[Is there any way to check if migrations are ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454494/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-migrations-are-ended)

This is the link with the decent answer but i couldn't understand enough.

**Ignore this**

```
if ($userData['grant_type'] == 'refresh_token') {
            $validator = Validator::make($userData, Config::get('boilerplate.refresh_token.validation_rules'));
        } elseif ($userData['grant_type'] == 'password') {
            $validator = Validator::make($userData, Config::get('boilerplate.login.validation_rules'));
        }
```

Comment: You can add data migrations in migration file - just use `DB::statement()`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the most simple way to do it using the database event `MigrationsEnded`.

First, Create a new service provider class, example:

`php artisan make:provider CommandListenerProvider`

Then, Add this to your new provider, example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Event;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsEnded;

class CommandListenerProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen(MigrationsEnded::class, function (MigrationsEnded $event) {
            
            // What will happen when a migration ends
            dump('You can set your logic here');
        });
    }
}
```

Register your provider in `config/app.php` inside `providers` array.

```
'providers' => [
       ....
       App\Providers\CommandListenerProvider::class,
 ],
```

To test it, just run `php artisan migrate` and you should get the same text in the `dump()` function. `"You can set your logic here"` in the terminal/console.

Then, you're ready to go!

Comment: Why ServiceProvider? You can use standard listener for catching this event.

Comment: @Maksim a service provider is where you register your listener regardless of where the listener callback is though. It's probably easier to follow the answer when there's not a lot of files involved, though you don't actually need a new service provider, the `EventServiceProvider` is there for these sort of things

Comment: @apokryfos yes, for first - you have a `EventServiceProvider`. But, in my opinion, dedicated listener is much more maintainable way for event listening than callbacks

Comment: @Maksim My point is you still need to register the listener in a provider though

Comment: You both have a good point, you can do it in multiple ways. But because of the event is within the command level (Out of the app in that sense) and the logic which can be added to that event can be big, nasty or whatever, simply I choose the provider to keep it clear and anything belongs to the command can be there  Ex: in case later he needs to add events like `CommandStarting`/ `CommandFinished` ... ☕️

Answer (score 0):

You should create a listener not a Service provider like above.

You want to listen to the `MigrationsEnded` event, you can create a listener like so.

Then You need to register the event listener in the EventServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsEnded;

class MigrationsEndedListener
{
    /**
     * @param MigrationsEnded $migrationsEnded
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MigrationsEnded $migrationsEnded): void
    {
         // TODO Add Logic Here
    }
}
```

**EventServiceProvider**

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        MigrationsEnded::class => [
            MigrationsEndedListener::class
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }
}
```